# CMake Using Ninja Generator Path Issue

Tags: windows, cmake, ninja

I'm using cmake with ninja generator in Windows. But it seems the generated path contains a dollar sign. It seems the variable `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG` and `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE` will contain a dollar sign when cmake creating the build.ninja here, is the sample generated path with dollar sign,

```
D$:\Worspace\branch\dev
```

I can't build because ninja always tell that cannot find path.

Please advise.

Comment: What version of CMake and ninja do you use? In general $: is a escaped sequence for : _(This is only necessary in build lines, where a colon would otherwise terminate the list of outputs.)_ from [ninja manual](http://martine.github.io/ninja/manual.html)
Have you checked that the folder really exist by typing "dir D:\Worspace\branch\dev"? Maybe you wanted to type Wor*k*space..?